# Angular 6 library

Tags: angular

I'm developing a library with Angular 6 (https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11), but I'm blocking with adding project dependency. I want to create a library that is independent of my project with dependencies of its own. I thought to modify the package.json and add my dependency inside but it does not work.

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

then i thought in the ng-package.json but the same thing

`angular-in-memory-web-api must be explicitly whitelisted.`

Help me :)

Comment: try add into the peerdependencies and your project's package.json to install as dependency. The peerdependency is not a must but the last one is.

Comment: I tried but without success :(

Comment: It works for me. I've added any deps for the parent(root, main) package.json and nothing into the libary's package.json. npm i and works everything and IDE(sometimes restart required) can see them too.

Comment: I tried it too, but I would dissociate my library to the parent, so I can install it everywhere

Comment: You can, just add to peerdeps and add your deps for your projects as well. For libraries there are no nested node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the `ng-package.json` file inside your library folder adding the `whitelistedNonPeerDependencies` attribute with all the modules that need to be whitelisted.

```
{
    "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "dest": "../../dist/my-lib",
    "deleteDestPath": false,
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts"
    },
    "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
        "angular-in-memory-web-api"
    ]
}
```